# If you solo mine through the GUI, version 0.17.1.9-3ca5f10f (Qt5.15.2), how or where would you get paid if you were lucky enough to earn anything?

Tags: mining

If you solo mine and you got lucky enough to earn something, how would you get the Monero? Also, how would you know if you happen to earn something? I understand solo mining is prob not going to ever earn me much if anything, but I still wanted to solo mine some at least to help out the Monero community. And it's easier to just click start mining in my GUI I think. At least right now while I'm still newish at Monero. Do you need to put a receiving address somewhere before you click the "start mining" icon in your GUI? Or would you get sent any earnings to your account's wallet main address maybe? I hope you can understand what I'm asking. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do find a block, you will get a new transaction to your wallet with the block reward on it - currently about 1.1 monero. If you have several wallets, it will go to the one that was loaded at the time you started mining.